# Using Powershell to set a static IP on a disconnected network card, is it possible?

Tags: powershell, networking, ip-address

I need to set the IP address of a NIC on Windows 10 while it is not connected to a network.  I've tried:

```
Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -IPAddress "192.168.5.10" -PrefixLength 24
```

and

```
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -IPAddress "192.168.5.10" -PrefixLength 24
```

Set-NetIPAddress does not return any errors, but it doesn't set the address.  It *does* toggle the selection in IPV4 properties to use a specific address, but does not fill in the values.

New-NetIPAddress gives the following error:

```
New-NetIPAddress : Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and     Dhcp Enabled
At line:1 char:1
+ New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -IPAddress "192.168.5.10" -Pr     ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress) [New-NetIPAddress], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-NetIPAddress
```

I did some digging and found here: http://www.darrylvanderpeijl.nl/tag/policystore/ that the NIC needs a connection before configuring the IP address.

Basically I am trying to set the IP address for add-on NICS in hundreds of computers.  This particular NIC will not have a connection until the computer is in production. I'm still pretty new to Powershell, is it even possible to configure the IP address of a disconnected NIC?

I'm open to trying other technologies if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind...

```
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" static 192.168.5.10 255.255.255.0
```

does exactly that and can be run from a .ps1 script.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you find disconnected adapters

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 7" | select netconnectionid, name, InterfaceIndex, netconnectionstatus
```