# Set static IP via PowerShell command not fully working

Tags: vb.net, powershell, ip

I am working with PowerShell command in desktop application (Visual Basic) to change the network adapter setting either using DHCP or static IP configuration. The command worked but it does not appear in Internet Protocol (TCP/IPv4) settings and only showing with ipconfig command via cmd. [IP not shows in control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/defUS.png)

The problem rises if the user reboot or the network adapter restarted by itself. It will causes the static IP disappeared. So that user must change network to static IP configuration again.

**UPDATED**
Below my PowerShell command, I set DHCP first incase user accidently connect to network with DHCP configurations.

```
    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "PowerShell.exe"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "netsh wlan disconnect ;" & " Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias \""" & Adapter & "\"" -AddressFamily IPv4 | Remove-NetRoute -AddressFamily IPv4 -Confirm:$false " + ";" + " Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias \""" & Adapter & "\"" -AddressFamily IPv4 | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Enabled " + ";" + " Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias \""" & Adapter & "\"" -AddressFamily IPv4 | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ResetServerAddresses ; " & "New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias \""" & Adapter & "\"" -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress " & IP & " -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway " & Gateway & " ; Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias \""" & Adapter & "\"" -ServerAddresses " & DNS1 & "," & DNS2
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    p.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()
```

Same issues asked here (https://superuser.com/questions/1683252/setting-static-ip-via-powershell-doesnt-work)

**UPDATE**
Tried running using the command directly PowerShell.exe, it work flawlessly. IP not disappear after reboot. Might problem from process vb net?

Comment: VB.NET and Powershell (and any other .NET language such as C#) call the exact same functions in the .NET Framework. The .NET Framework calls the same Windows API functions as all other non .NET languages.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it does not much relate into any causes of this issues. It is all about configuring static IP through PowerShell command. @Lundt

Comment: There's an unmatched quote after `-Confirm:$false ;`. Make sure you have pasted the code as-is, since typos might affect the script's outcome.

Comment: I already update the code same exactly with my desktop application. Unmatched quote is not exist in my desktop program, it only in question for more readable. Thanks for your alert @vonPryz

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that cannot set the static IP properly on disconnected NIC when using command `New-NetIPAddress`, it will cause the static disappeared once machine is restarted or the NIC is re-enable. [References](http://www.darrylvanderpeijl.com/inconsistent-parameters-policystore-persistentstore-and-dhcp-enabled/)

Instead, use netsh command to properly set the static IP.
[netsh worked on disconnected NIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385742/using-powershell-to-set-a-static-ip-on-a-disconnected-network-card-is-it-possib)